# "My name is" or "My name's"

Tags: grammar, contractions, be

Can you contract the verb to be in this case?

"My name's", "his name's", "her name's".... sound a little bit off to me, or at least sounds very, very informal.

Most important question is "is it grammatically correct" or not.

Comment: You can say "My name's Eric" or "His name's Steve", if that's what you mean.  Contracting **is** to **'s** is common in a variety of contexts.

Comment: If you're learning English, you might find the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) site useful.

Comment: ... is Slim Shady 

Answer (score 3):

According to [APA style](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/12/contractions-in-formal-writing-whats-allowed-whats-not.html), contractions are allowed but considered less formal. Your use of contraction is correct but not recommended in, say, an academic paper.

An excerpt from the above link:

> Contractions are a part of informal writing. Thus, avoid contractions in scholarly writing, except for under the following circumstances:
>
> - If you are reproducing a direct quotation that contains a contraction
>     (e.g., a quotation from a research participant), leave the contraction as-is.
> - If you are writing about contractions (e.g., in a    paper about language), naturally you must be able to use contractions    as
>     linguistic examples.
> - If you are reproducing an idiom that contains    a contraction (e.g., “don’t count your chickens before they hatch”),    leave the
>     contraction (no need for “do not count your chickens…”).
> - If you are making an off-the-cuff or informal remark within an otherwise    formal paper, it is okay to use a contraction as part of
>     your writing voice. You might find this kind of remark in a
>     footnote or a parenthetical statement. Scientific writing should
>     be formal but it doesn’t have to be stuffy. It is okay to have a
>     moment of informality as long as the overall tone is appropriately
>     formal.